# Modify a string from a stucture

Tags: c, string, pointers, structure

I have a some problems writing a code in which I want to modify a file extension stored in a string.For example string `bla/bla/file.icc` i want to be changed to `bla/bla/file.cmr`. This string makes part from a structure. I have 2 issues. One is that `strcpy` gives this message "expected expression before `td_ActDOR` and second one is in for and give's this message `subscribed value is neither array nor pointer`.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct s_ActDOR
{
    char pDOR_file[86];
}td_ActDOR;


int main(void)
{
    char path[80]="blabla/blabla/aici.icc";
    td_ActDOR *Obiect;
    Obiect = (td_ActDOR *)malloc(sizeof (td_ActDOR));

    strcpy(td_ActDOR->pDOR_file, "blabla/blabla/file.icc");

    int path_lenght=strlen(td_ActDOR->pDOR_file);
    int i;
    char bla[4] = "rmc\0";
    printf("Stringul before: %s\n",path);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Obiect->pDOR_file[path_lenght-(i+1)] = bla[i];
    }
    printf("Stringul after: %s\n",path);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: `pActDORwrk` is not declared

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `td_ActDOR` is not a variable, (it's a type), `Obiect` is.

Change

```
  strcpy(td_ActDOR->pDOR_file, "blabla/blabla/file.icc");
```

to

```
 strcpy(Obiect->pDOR_file, "blabla/blabla/file.icc");
```

Same goes for `strlen(td_ActDOR->pDOR_file);`, too.

Comment: thank's this is for 1st issue. Do you have any  advice for the second one?

Comment: @AndreiCristian I'm confused...did you make the change and run? Is it still there?

Comment: @AndreiCristian also, `pActDORwrk` seems missing here...

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks for the fix. Copy-paste....

Comment: So  i made the changed runned and in this small example that i made here is working fine. I have a large and i'm passing a pointer of this structure to a function where i want to modify the extension and the for loop is the same as here but is not working. Im really confused now.